# Closure of interior of closure of an open set is its closure

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove that
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{Cl}[\text{Int}(\text{Cl}A)]=\text{Cl}A
\end{eqnarray}
for any open subset $A$ in a space $X$, and Cl means closure and Int means interior.

That LHS contains RHS is obvious, while my question is about the other direction that I have no idea.

Comment: $Int(Cl(A)) \subseteq Cl(A)$. Take closure on both sides.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the concise comment of hint!